# Conflict on the meaning of * when including Org mode files in a calendar diary

Tags: org-mode, calendar, diary

I want to include org-mode files into the default diary file of calendar mode, but there is a problem: the * symbol is used to match unspecific day. for example,

```
** 2nd heading
```

in the ~/diary file would generate "2nd heading" to appear each day. Is it possible to change how the calendar/diary mode mark unspecific day? like change * to % ?

Comment: Can you give an example of how you enter the unspecific days? Org interprets a line beginning with one or more `*` **followed** by a space as a heading. I haven't used diary but from [this](http://sunsite.univie.ac.at/textbooks/emacs/emacs_33.html) example, a diary entry with unspecific date can look like `*/25`. That won't be interpreted as a heading as there is no space after `*`.

Comment: ** is interpreted as any month any day